# How to start up an Android Activity from another application?

Tags: android, android-activity, sim-toolkit

I'm trying to write an App that starts the Android STK Activity as follows:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(); 
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.stk", "com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity")); 
            startActivity(intent);
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.stk/com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I've declared the following in my manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity"/>
```

Comment: just compare: `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.stk", "com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity"));` and `... {com.android.stk/com.android.stk2.StkLauncherActivity}...` ... do you see **stk2** because i see...

Comment: Yes, that was a typo here, stk doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

try using [PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) which return an intent to launch a front-door activity in  given package :

```
   PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); 
   Intent intent =manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.stk"); 
   if (intent != null)  
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: try it i'm sure this will work if you are passing correct PackageName

Comment: The intent is null... I'm pretty sure that the PackageName is correct.

Comment: @Yusufk then see here when it's returning NULL http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Ok, looks like the package did not intend a front-door launch. Any ideas on how to do a back-door launch?

Comment: @Yusufk : see here http://code.google.com/codesearch#oOy_5JrVRNM/trunk/packages/apps/Stk/AndroidManifest.xml&type=cs `StkLauncherActivity` Activity declared with `android:enabled="false"` means component  are disabled

Comment: @Yusufk : but this application have other activities like `StkSettings`,`StkMenuActivity` and `StkInputActivity` you ca try these activities to lauch but `StkLauncherActivity` is not enabled for third party application

Comment: Yes, I tried these, and they do behave better, but it does not launch the STK menu, which is what I've been trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: @Yusufk : were you able to find a solution to open com.android.stk from your app?

Comment: @Anuj Sharma: if you were successful opening sim toolkit can you explain how you did it?

Comment: @nous - It was so long ago, I can't even remember this question or why I needed to do this. Something tells me I didn't get this to work though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo on your side

```
com.android.stk/com.android.stk2.StkLauncherActivity
```

`stk` or `stk2`? :)

Comment: stk - that should not have been on the post

Answer (score 0):

To launch an activity from another app,you can set "action"  in the activity intent filter of android manifest of app in which your activity belong.And while launching set the same "action"to the intent

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would look?

Comment: For example in the Avtivity to be called ,set Intent filter in Android Manifest as <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.nargis.action.MYACTIVITY" />          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> And now while startingActivity through Intent ,set action of Intent as "com.example.nargis.action.MYACTIVITY",this should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code snippet

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.abc.xyz", "com.abc.xyz.MainActivity");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent);
```